# Splitting up EDI orders

Tags: edi, edifact

We are implementing edi order processing and are currently about to check how we set up the interface.

Usually a order may carry multiple positions. For our customer it seems that an incoming order may need to be split up in multiple orders if they will be manufactured in different factories due to erp system requirements.

For me its sounds confusing if a customer does one order and gets back 3 different order numbers. One solution could be one position per order policy, however this increases the number of orders even when not needed.

The customer is sending an "ORDERS" message and will receive an order confirmation "ORDRSP".

I'm wondering whats the common solution to solve this problem? Manually keeping track of the sub orders thems to be no option has they are confirmed at different times, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

different solutions:

1. You split up orders: retailer will receive different shipments, different ASN's, etc (all referring to the same RetailersOrderNumber). But...not all retailers want this/can handle this.
2. Retailer splits up the orders (in most cases this means you will be 3 different manufacturers in their system ;-)
3. Factories deliver to one (manufacturers) DC where all the order/shipment handling is done.

(AFAIK these are the possibilities....)

kind regards, henk-jan